# Did Lord Buddha preach not to believe our own minds?

Tags: reference-request, teaching

Has Lord Buddha preached that we shouldn't believe our own minds?

If he did, what is the meaning of that saying?

**Update:** Are there any meaning other than *ignorence*, *Ilusion* ? Like Uncertainty of mind, changing mind ?

Answer (score 2):

"Now suppose that a magician or magician's apprentice were to display a magic trick at a major intersection, and a man with good eyesight were to see it, observe it, & appropriately examine it. To him — seeing it, observing it, & appropriately examining it — it would appear empty, void, without substance: for what substance would there be in a magic trick? In the same way, a monk sees, observes, & appropriately examines any consciousness that is past, future, or present; internal or external; blatant or subtle; common or sublime; far or near. To him — seeing it, observing it, & appropriately examining it — it would appear empty, void, without substance: for what substance would there be in consciousness?

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.095.than.html

Answer (score 0):

This is related to mental proliferation or [*papañca*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26819/471) - also called reification or objectification-classification. Also, see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/30898/471) and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/30460/471).

From Piya Tan's [commentary on MN 18](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.14-Madhupindika-S-m18-piya.pdf) (the **bolded** parts answer your question, on why not to trust your mental proliferations as being absolutely true):

> 3.2.1.1 The Madhupiṇḍika Sutta (M 18) gives us a very helpful
>   explanation of the process involving mental proliferation: this is
>   given in some detail in §§16+17, the Sutta's key passages. §16
>   describes how mental proliferation tenaciously grips us as we
>   unconsciously follow its dictates through our sense-experiences.
>   Essentially, this domination begins any of our sense-experience: when
>   a sense-faculty, and its respective sense-object and consciousness
>   (attention) come together, there is contact (*phassa*), that is, a
>   sense-experience. This, in turn, generates feeling (*vedanā*), how we
>   see pleasure in something perceive as being attractive, pain in what
>   is repulsive, and boredom in the neutral. This perception (*saññā*),
>   in turn, generates thinking (*vitakka*), and when we think in this
>   way, we mentally proliferate (*papañceti*). Notice that *papañceti* is
>   a passive verb: we have no control over such an unconscious process. **We
>   simply explode into countless conceptions (*saṅkhā*) and perceptions
>   (*saññā*) about the past, the future and the present
>   sense-experiences. We run after the past, conjure up the future, and
>   misconstrue the present, creating our own world of these misfits of
>   thoughts and imaginings. We are being processed by our mental
>   proliferation.**

And also:

> 3.2.1.3  Mental proliferation (*papañca*) works hand in glove with how our sense-experiences, how we sense things. It is rooted in our
>   unconscious mind, that is, the latent tendencies, so that we are not
>   aware what is going on: we are deprived of our free will (in fact, we
>   do not have it yet). The full term for mental proliferation
>   (*papañca*) is *papañca*, *saññā*, *saṅkhā*, which gives us the key
>   words for the working of mental proliferation. *Saññā*, although
>   related to the “perception” of the 5 aggregates, here it is very much
>   like consciousness (*viññāṇa*). It works like consciousness, basically
>   aware of sense-objects, but it also evaluates and value-add them,
>   "recognizing" them from our past experiences. In other words, we only
>   allow the familiar into our lives, or perceive all or experiences as
>   we desire them, not as they really are *Saṅkhā*, too, works like our
>   consciousness but we are here attending to the perceptions we have
>   been accumulating. **Its only task is that of projecting notions and
>   imaginings: what we desire, what we hate, what we are deluded with,
>   what we fear. This is, in fact, how our “creative” minds work,
>   measuring ourselves against others, creating problems for us, and
>   lurking insidiously behind our thinking, and at the roots of all
>   religions, including religious Buddhism.** Mental proliferation, then,
>   comprises of perceiving (*saññā*) and notion-forming (*saṅkhā*) or
>   conceiving (*maññanā*) — is an explosion of mental constructs created
>   by the power of the latent tendencies (*anusaya*) of craving
>   (*taṇhā*), views (*diṭṭhi*) and conceit (*māna*).

The list of latent or underlying tendencies are found in [AN 7.11](https://suttacentral.net/an7.11/en/sujato) (translated by Bhikkhu Sujato):

> “Mendicants, there are these seven underlying tendencies. What seven?
>   The underlying tendencies of sensual desire, repulsion, views, doubt,
>   conceit, desire to be reborn, and ignorance. These are the seven
>   underlying tendencies.”

The "desire to be reborn" (*bhavarāgānusaya*) is translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.011.than.html) as "passion for becoming".